# How to get current setup directory for the script section?

Tags: inno-setup

Under the `[Run]` section I want to change the working directory to the directory from which the installer was executed. For example, if the setup was executed from the Desktop, I want the working directory to point to the Desktop:

```
Filename: "{app}\setup.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; MinVersion: 0.0,6.0; Flags: skipifsilent
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`{src}`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_consts.htm#src) constant. The documentation describes it as:

> **{src}**
>
> The directory in which the Setup files are located. For example: If
> you used `{src}\MYPROG.EXE` on an entry and the user is installing from
> `"S:\"`, Setup will translate it to `"S:\MYPROG.EXE"`.

In your case you can use it like:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\setup.exe"; WorkingDir: "{src}"; MinVersion: 0.0,6.0; Flags: skipifsilent
```